# view containing a union with a clean select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Being quite new to SQL , I'm struggling to expand the following query sine I needed another condition in the following query I decided to try and use another CASE in the ELSE part of the statement. 
I'll past the statement below :

```
 /* AZURE_COMMENT_START */
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Caring')
    CREATE DATABASE [Caring]
GO

USE [Caring]
GO
/* AZURE_COMMENT_END */


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE [name] = 'tlv_plannings')
    DROP VIEW [tlv_plannings]
GO

CREATE VIEW tlv_plannings AS 
(

    SELECT
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Id] AS [Id],
    2 AS [Weekday],
    [FrequentieMao] AS [FrequentieMorning],
    [FrequentieMam] AS [FrequentieAfternoon],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Startdate] AS [Startdate],
    ISNULL(AanvragenPlanningBase.[Enddate], '9999-12-31') AS [Enddate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.MondayMorning ELSE ov2.MondayMorning END AS [MorningTime], 
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.MondayAfternoon ELSE ov2.MondayAfternoon END AS [AfternoonTime], 
    AanvragenPlanningBase.MondayMorning AS [PlanningMorning],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.MondayAfternoon AS [PlanningAfternoon],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.Startdate ELSE ov2.Startdate END AS [OpvangStartdate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(ov1.Enddate, '9999-12-31') ELSE  ISNULL(ov2.Enddate, '9999-12-31') END AS [OpvangEnddate]
    FROM AanvragenPlanningBase
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudKdvOpvangtijdBase kov on AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov1 ON ov1.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudBSoOpvangtijdBase bov on AanvragenPlanningBase.BSOOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov2 ON ov2.BsoOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    UNION 
    SELECT
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Id] AS [Id],
    3 AS [Weekday],
    [FrequentieDio] AS [FrequentieMorning],
    [FrequentieDim] AS [FrequentieAfternoon],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Startdate] AS [Startdate],
    ISNULL(AanvragenPlanningBase.[Enddate], '9999-12-31') AS [Enddate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.TuesdayMorning ELSE ov2.TuesdayMorning END AS [MorningTime], 
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.TuesdayAfternoon ELSE ov2.TuesdayAfternoon END AS [AfternoonTime], 
    AanvragenPlanningBase.TuesdayMorning AS [PlanningMorning],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.TuesdayAfternoon AS [PlanningAfternoon],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.Startdate ELSE ov2.Startdate END AS [OpvangStartdate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(ov1.Enddate, '9999-12-31') ELSE  ISNULL(ov2.Enddate, '9999-12-31') END AS [OpvangEnddate]
    FROM AanvragenPlanningBase
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudKdvOpvangtijdBase kov on AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov1 ON ov1.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudBSoOpvangtijdBase bov on AanvragenPlanningBase.BSOOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov2 ON ov2.BsoOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    UNION 
    SELECT
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Id] AS [Id],
    4 AS [Weekday],
    [FrequentieWoo] AS [FrequentieMorning],
    [FrequentieWom] AS [FrequentieAfternoon],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Startdate] AS [Startdate],
    ISNULL(AanvragenPlanningBase.[Enddate], '9999-12-31') AS [Enddate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.WednesdayMorning ELSE ov2.WednesdayMorning END AS [MorningTime], 
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.WednesdayAfternoon ELSE ov2.WednesdayAfternoon END AS [AfternoonTime], 
    AanvragenPlanningBase.WednesdayMorning AS [PlanningMorning],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.WednesdayAfternoon AS [PlanningAfternoon],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.Startdate ELSE ov2.Startdate END AS [OpvangStartdate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(ov1.Enddate, '9999-12-31') ELSE  ISNULL(ov2.Enddate, '9999-12-31') END AS [OpvangEnddate]
    FROM AanvragenPlanningBase
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudKdvOpvangtijdBase kov on AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov1 ON ov1.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudBSoOpvangtijdBase bov on AanvragenPlanningBase.BSOOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov2 ON ov2.BsoOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    UNION 
    SELECT
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Id] AS [Id],
    5 AS [Weekday],
    [FrequentieDoo] AS [FrequentieMorning],
    [FrequentieDom] AS [FrequentieAfternoon],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Startdate] AS [Startdate],
    ISNULL(AanvragenPlanningBase.[Enddate], '9999-12-31') AS [Enddate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.ThursdayMorning ELSE ov2.ThursdayMorning END AS [MorningTime], 
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.ThursdayAfternoon ELSE ov2.ThursdayAfternoon END AS [AfternoonTime], 
    AanvragenPlanningBase.ThursdayMorning AS [PlanningMorning],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.ThursdayAfternoon AS [PlanningAfternoon],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.Startdate ELSE ov2.Startdate END AS [OpvangStartdate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(ov1.Enddate, '9999-12-31') ELSE  ISNULL(ov2.Enddate, '9999-12-31') END AS [OpvangEnddate]
    FROM AanvragenPlanningBase
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudKdvOpvangtijdBase kov on AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov1 ON ov1.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudBSoOpvangtijdBase bov on AanvragenPlanningBase.BSOOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov2 ON ov2.BsoOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    UNION 
    SELECT
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Id] AS [Id],
    6 AS [Weekday],
    [FrequentieVro] AS [FrequentieMorning],
    [FrequentieVrm] AS [FrequentieAfternoon],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.[Startdate] AS [Startdate],
    ISNULL(AanvragenPlanningBase.[Enddate], '9999-12-31') AS [Enddate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.FridayMorning ELSE ov2.FridayMorning END AS [MorningTime], 
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.FridayAfternoon ELSE ov2.FridayAfternoon END AS [AfternoonTime], 
    AanvragenPlanningBase.MondayMorning AS [PlanningMorning],
    AanvragenPlanningBase.MondayAfternoon AS [PlanningAfternoon],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ov1.Startdate ELSE ov2.Startdate END AS [OpvangStartdate],
    CASE WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(ov1.Enddate, '9999-12-31') ELSE  ISNULL(ov2.Enddate, '9999-12-31') END AS [OpvangEnddate]
    FROM AanvragenPlanningBase
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudKdvOpvangtijdBase kov on AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov1 ON ov1.KdvOpvangtijdId = kov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudBSoOpvangtijdBase bov on AanvragenPlanningBase.BSOOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OnderhoudOpvangtijdBase ov2 ON ov2.BsoOpvangtijdId = bov.Id
)
```

So the problems arise in the following part(s)

```
 ELSE  ISNULL(ov2.Enddate, '9999-12-31') END AS [OpvangEnddate]
```

Now here is where I wanted to put another case select in but I have a lot of trouble with the syntax(forgive me ) since I wanted to match the number of columns in this query. How can I do this properly and in a clean manner?

Comment: `9999-12-31`? That's not exactly Y10k compliant...

Comment: I can't tell from the question what the problem is. Are you getting an error or unexpected data?

Comment: @Marc  sorry it is a query I have to adjust, so not my code but you're right

Comment: @Karl I'm expecting an error(also getting it) but I found all the case selects a bit confusing and ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you have several possibilities for `[OpvangEnddate]`, you probably want something like this. I've added carriage returns to make it clear that the `CASE...END` structure can have many clauses:

```
CASE 
    WHEN AanvragenPlanningBase.KdvOpvangtijdId IS NOT NULL 
      THEN ISNULL(ov1.Enddate, '9999-12-31') 
    WHEN 'something else' = 'is true'
      THEN 'some other value'
    ELSE  
      ISNULL(ov2.Enddate, '9999-12-31') 
END AS [OpvangEnddate]
```